# Is it good to implement equals() for control flow?

Tags: java, set, equals, object-oriented-analysis

Let's say that I have a class `Item`, that has a lot of fields, one of them is `color`.
and I have another class `Holder` that stores instances of `Item`.
Each `Holder` can have any number of instances of `Item` as long as there are not more than one of each `Color` present.

Does it make sense to implement `equals()` in a way that returns true whenever the colors of two items are equal, to use a `Set` of items inside of Holder? Or should I make `equals` return true only when all fields are equal and use another logic to implement the `Holder` logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `equals()` should either compare the entire object, or should compare a *natural* unique value, e.g. an ID or some item code.

Color is not a natural unique identifier of an item, so do not implement `equals()` to compare that.

Instead, use a `TreeSet` with a custom `Comparator` that compares `color`.

Alternatively, use a `Map` keyed by `color`.

Answer (score 3):

1. It is good to create an override for your class's equals and hashCode methods.
2. The main consideration should be what truly makes an instance of the class unique, what *defines* and *specifies* it.
3. If it is well and fully defined by the color property, then so be it (although this sounds at least on first view to be unlikely).
4. If not, then it would be best *not* to use the color field as the sole field that determines uniqueness since you don't know how you might be using instances of the class in the future.